# Batch file put user input in a txt file in a different directory

Tags: batch-file

This is my code. I want all the input it gets to go into one txt file in a certain different directory.

```
@echo off

echo Type in your song name and who it is by then press enter twice

:start
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
echo Your input was: %INPUT%
pause
echo %INPUT%  temp.txt
goto :start
```

Answer (score 1):

**Save input into text file:**

`echo %input% > file.txt`
**or**
`echo %input% >> file.txt`

Using `>` will overwrite the entire file, then add `%input%` to it.

Using `>>` will simply add `%input%` onto the next line of the file.

If the text file doesn't exist yet, it will automatically be created.

**Move text file into desired directory:**

`MOVE file.txt <new-directory>`

It's pretty self-explanatory. More information about the `MOVE` command can be found by opening the CMD, then entering `MOVE /?`.

Hope this helped.

Comment: no need to `move`, when you redirect directly like `echo %INPUT% >>"c:\certain directory\temp.txt"`

Comment: @Stephan Yeah, you could, but my poor 15 year old vocabulary doesn't know how to explain that, and put it into words, lol.